# Why the search results are wrong in search posts form?

Tags: search

I want to search some posts which contain characters **awk  -v **in my wordpress.

1.to search it with mysql select command.

```
select guid,post_title  from wp_posts where post_content like  '%awk%-v%';
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| guid                        | post_title                            |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| http://hwy.local/wp/?p=3323 | 文本处理工具awk                       |
| http://hwy.local/wp/?p=3330 | 格式化a链接：添加属性和值             |
| http://hwy.local/wp/?p=3339 | 文本处理工具awk                       |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

[image]

2.to search it in search posts.

[image]

Why the two search results are totally different?
It is verified that all the search results in search posts form are wrong ,all the the search results with sql command are right.
Why the search results are wrong in search posts form?
All the four search results searched in search posts form opened ,none of them contain characters both **awk** and **-v**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the_search_query() to look at the last search query run by WordPress. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query